# Clicking on button not working in selenium + scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I want to scrape links to news articles using scrapy + selenium. The website I am using uses a 'Load more' button, so I obviously want selenium to click on this button to load all articles.
I have looked for similar questions and tried various options already such as

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="fusion-app"]/main/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/button')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

and

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ais-InfiniteHits-loadMore")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

All to no result. I've also inserted some print statements in between to check whether it does run the code, and that seems to work fine; I think it's just a matter of the button not being located/clicked on.

This is the html of the button btw:

```
<button class="ais-InfiniteHits-loadMore">Load more </button>
```

And when I print `element`, this is what I get: `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="545716eef622a12bdbeddef99e02bdef", element="551741ec-4616-4bd4-b8fd-57c2f4bffb00")>`

Is someone able to help me out? Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you share the URL ?

Comment: Sure; [https://www.businessoffashion.com/search/?q=Louis+Vuitton&f=Articles%2CFashion+Shows%2CNews](https://www.businessoffashion.com/search/?q=Louis+Vuitton&f=Articles%2CFashion+Shows%2CNews)

Comment: I think you need to handle the cookie pop up which is displayed at the bottom of the page…

Comment: better create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run. And we could use it to create solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get('https://www.businessoffashion.com/search/?q=Louis+Vuitton&f=Articles%2CFashion+Shows%2CNews')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'button.ab-close-button'))).click()
elem=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ais-InfiniteHits-loadMore")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", elem)
```

You hit two different errors with a pop up and an element click intereception when you can just use javascript to click that element.

Import:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```